# Why does my progress bar shows full progress value before it start loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I made a progress bar using jQuery UI. here is the link to see it: [**DEMO**](http://goo.gl/DwS9lF)

It works well, just there is a problem. At the code I have `setTimeout( progress, 2000 );` which means it has to wait 2 seconds before it stars. But during this time it shows the background of .ui-progressbar-value which must be visible when the whole progress is completed.  After 2 seconds it hides and to progress stars as normal.

Interestingly when I tried it on JSFiddle, it did not show this class and worked perfectly. So in browsers only have this problem. **[Here is the JSFiddel link](http://jsfiddle.net/aEBuq/)**

and this is my js code:

```
$(function() {
    var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
      progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

    progressbar.progressbar({
      value: false,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
      },
      complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "100%" );
        $(".loader").delay(1000).fadeOut(750);
      }
    });

    function progress() {
      var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

      progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );

      if ( val < 100 ) {
        setTimeout( progress, 100 );
      }

    }

    setTimeout( progress, 2000 );
  });
```

And CSS:

```
.enterance{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:black;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    z-index:10;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.enterance .loader{
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -300px;
}
.ui-progressbar-value {
    background:url(http://goo.gl/V9dAfn) no-repeat;
    width:600px;
    height:429px;
    border:0;
}
.ui-progressbar{
    background:url(http://goo.gl/rBH0N1) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:600px;
    height:429px;
    border:0;
}
.ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value{margin:0;}
.progress-label{
    font-size:90px;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    right:0px; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

So how can I NOT show this `.ui-progressbar-value` while it's waiting for 2 seconds? And Additionally, how can I add a fadeIn effect to this? like when page loads the image fades in ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bits e will have some content later on,why should we bother abt that.
Pretty good loader too btw :)

Comment: @bits It is not the whole project. And for the website I am working on, it really needs a fake loader. However, the problem is what I described in the main question. Do u have any idea to fix that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (can't be sure unless you had a fiddle of the issue):

```
$(function() {
    var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
      progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

    progressbar.progressbar({
      value: false,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
      },
      complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "100%" );
        $(".loader").delay(1000).fadeOut(750);
      }
    });

    function progress() {
      var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

      progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );

      if ( val < 100 ) {
        setTimeout( progress, 100 );
      }
    }

    progressbar.progressbar( "value", 0 );
    setTimeout( progress, 2000 );
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It starts loading as soon as the page is loaded. But it must wait couple of seconds then starts.

Comment: The same thing. progress starts as soon as it loads. :/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to revert previous change. Try now.

Comment: Awww, I just changed something in your answer and it worked. I removed `progress();`  and added `setTimeout( progress, 2000 );` and it is working now.

Comment: Just one more additional thing that is not related to this topic but is it possible to have a fadeIn() effect when the progress bar loads ?

Comment: All I did was to add `display:none;` in css for `.enterance .loader` and added `$(".loader").delay(1000).fadeIn(750);` right before the first `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "$(function()" and running just the plain code?

```
var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
      progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

    progressbar.progressbar({
      value: false,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
      },
      complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "100%" );
        $(".loader").delay(1000).fadeOut(750);
      }
    });

    function progress() {
      var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

      progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );

      if ( val < 100 ) {
        setTimeout( progress, 100 );
      }

    }

    setTimeout( progress, 2000 );
```

Cant really work on it cuz it doesnt affect the fiddle right?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried it, but it did not work. :(